# Creating Delegates With Lambda Expressions in F#

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming, delegates

Why does...

```
type IntDelegate = delegate of int -> unit

type ListHelper =
    static member ApplyDelegate (l : int list) (d : IntDelegate) =
        l |> List.iter (fun x -> d.Invoke x)

ListHelper.ApplyDelegate [1..10] (fun x -> printfn "%d" x)
```

not compile, when:

```
type IntDelegate = delegate of int -> unit

type ListHelper =
    static member ApplyDelegate (l : int list, d : IntDelegate) =
        l |> List.iter (fun x -> d.Invoke x)

ListHelper.ApplyDelegate ([1..10], (fun x -> printfn "%d" x))
```

does?

The only difference that is that in the second one, `ApplyDelegate` takes its parameters as a tuple.

> This function takes too many arguments, or is used in a context where a function is not expected

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I haven't looked at the spec to confirm, but I am guessing that the implicit conversion from "lambda" to "named delegate type" only occurs in a "member invocations".

You can always make the conversion explicit:

```
ListHelper.ApplyDelegate [1..10] (IntDelegate(fun x -> printfn "%d" x))
```

(The error diagnostic is quite poor; I'll file a bug.)

EDIT:

For the wonks...

Yeah, the [spec](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html) says

> 8.13.6   Type-directed Conversions at member invocations As described in
>   Method Application Resolution (see
>   §14.4), two type-directed conversions
>   are applied at method invocations.
>
> If a formal parameter is of delegate
>   type DelegateType, and an actual
>   argument is syntactically a function
>   value (fun ...), then the parameter is
>   interpreted as if it had been written
>   new DelegateType(fun ...).

that lambdas get converted automagically to delegate types only at "member invocations".  In the case of the curried member, the first argument passed is a member invocation, but then that returns a function value to apply the second argument, and function invocations do not have this implicit conversion rule.

Comment: Thank you. What exactly is a 'member invocation' and why does having tupled arguments make a difference?

Should members always take tupled arguments?

Comment: "Members" are things you define with the `member` keyword, e.g. static or instance methods on some type.  These contrast with "functions" which are defined via `let f x = ...` or `fun` and which are comparatively very strict (e.g. you cannot overload a function, but you can overload a member).  Members should probably always take tupled arguments, yes; members are more .NET-y entities, as compared to functions which are F#-specific.

Comment: The 'tupled arguments' makes a difference because when it's tupled, all the arguments are passed 'at once' to the member, so the second argument is an argument to a member.  In the case of curried arguments, the first argument is an argument to the member, and that results in a new (non-member) function value, which then takes the second argument.