# Delegate/Func conversion and misleading compiler error message

Tags: f#

I thought that conversions between F# functions and System.Func had to be done manually, but there appears to be a case where the compiler (sometimes) does it for you. And when it goes wrong the error message isn't accurate:

```
module Foo =
    let dict = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, System.Func<obj,obj>>()

    let f (x:obj) = x

    do
        // Question 1: why does this compile without explicit type conversion?
        dict.["foo"] <- fun (x:obj) -> x 
        // Question 2: given that the above line compiles, why does this fail?
        dict.["bar"] <- f
```

The last line fails to compile, and the error is:

```
This expression was expected to have type
    System.Func<obj,obj>    
but here has type
    'a -> obj
```

Clearly the function `f` doesn't have a signature of `'a > obj`. If the F# 3.1 compiler is happy with the first dictionary assignment, then why not the second?

Comment: I guess this is a case where the conversion isn't automatic, but the error isn't quite helpful, but is probably still technically correct.

Comment: I'd guess only the lambdas get converted automatially.

Comment: @MisterMetaphor: correct: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392000/interop-between-f-and-c-sharp-lambdas

Comment: But, wait, why is the type of `f` and `fun (x:obj) -> x` not the same? And what's up with the promotion to `f : 'a -> obj`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The part of the spec that should explain this is [8.13.7 Type Directed Conversions at Member Invocations](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc335818955).  In short, when invoking a member, an automatic conversion from an F# function to a delegate will be applied.  Unfortunately, the spec is a bit unclear; from the wording it seems that this conversion might apply to any function expression, but in practice it only appears to apply to anonymous function expressions.

The spec is also a bit out of date; in F# 3.0 type directed conversions also enable a conversion to a `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<SomeDelegateType>`.

**EDIT**

In looking at some past correspondence with the F# team, I think I've tracked down how a conversion could get applied to a non-syntactic function expression.  I'll include it here for completeness, but it's a bit of a strange corner case, so for most purposes you should probably consider the rule to be that only syntactic functions will have the type directed conversion applied.

The exception is that overload resolution can result in converting an arbitrary expression of function type; this is partly explained by section [14.4 Method Application Resolution](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc335819028), although it's pretty dense and still not entirely clear.  Basically, the argument expressions are only *elaborated* when there are multiple overloads; when there's just a single candidate method, the argument types are asserted against the unelaborated arguments (note: it's not obvious that this should actually matter in terms of whether the conversion is applicable, but it does matter empirically).  Here's an example demonstrating this exception:

```
type T =
    static member M(i:int) = "first overload"
    static member M(f:System.Func<int,int>) = "second overload"

let f i = i + 1

T.M f |> printfn "%s"
```

Comment: Nice. Apparently, the spec _used to_ specifically say that only lambda-expressions were so promoted; see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783450/creating-delegates-with-lambda-expressions-in-f). I wonder what the "other function-valued arguments" that gets converted now might be?

Comment: The part of the compiler doing this appears to be [this bit](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/typrelns.fs#L2202). I'm having difficulties working out what happens in the "not a lambda"-case, though. Can someone explain what happens here? Are there things besides lambdas which are automatically converted?

Comment: There is [F# language suggestion](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/248) to improve automatic conversion so that it works for cases with no candidate methods too.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This answer explains only the mysterious promotion to `'a -> obj`. @kvb points out that replacing `obj` with `int` in OPs example *still* doesn't work, so that promotion is in itself insufficient explanation for the observed behaviour.

---

To increase flexibility, the F# type elaborator may under certain conditions promote a named function from `f : SomeType -> OtherType` to    `f<'a where 'a :> SomeType> : 'a -> OtherType`. This is to reduce the need for upcasts. (See [spec. 14.4.2](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc335819030).)

Question 2 first:

```
dict["bar"] <- f                     (* Why does this fail? *)
```

Because `f` is a "named function", its type is promoted from `f : obj -> obj` following sec. 14.4.2 to the seemingly less restrictive `f<'a where 'a :> obj> : 'a -> obj`. But this type is incompatible with `System.Func<obj, obj>`.

Question 1:

```
dict["foo"] <- fun (x:obj) -> x      (* Why doesn't this, then?  *)
```

This is fine because the anonymous function is not named, and so sec. 14.4.2 does not apply. The type is never promoted from `obj -> obj` and so fits.

---

We can observe the interpreter exhibit behaviour following 14.4.2:

```
> let f = id : obj -> obj
val f : (obj -> obj)                         (* Ok, f has type obj -> obj *)
> f
val it : ('a -> obj) = <fun:it@135-31>       (* f promoted when used. *)
```

(The interpreter doesn't output constraints to `obj`.)

Comment: This isn't right; automatic promotion isn't involved (try the same example but with functions from `int` to `int`).